# How to remove the application from Google Play and how long it takes deactivation?

Tags: android, google-play

Of these two questions for me is more important to the second. I want to know how long the application will disappear from the store from the moment I have it disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making any changes to Google Play take about three to four hours before they appear for most users.

So un-publishing an app will not happen instantly.